# Can't login into deezer account from cURL

Tags: linux, terminal, curl

I can't authenticate into my deezer account from terminal using cURL, someone knows one workaround? I'm trying to authenticate with command below.

```
curl "https://www.deezer.com/us/login/email" \
    --data-urlencode "rememberMe=true" \
    --data-urlencode "email=my_email@gmail.com" \
    --data-urlencode "password=my_password" \
    --cookie "cookies.txt" \
    --cookie-jar "cookies.txt" \
    --location \
    --verbose > "login_log.html"
```

Comment: In general, trying to log into a website using `curl` will likely not succeed, and even if you do, you likely won't be able to make practical use of the site, since most sites require JavaScript.  You'd be better off seeing if Deezer has an API you can use.

Comment: I want to log in to get arl session of my user, theres one way to do it without log in from curl?